# How can i prefix forvmy user id in SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have created one table for user administration and i have created one unique ID for every user by using auto_increment .But now i want to make some prefix for my id like "fixname123" .

Answer (score 0):

To Query

```
select columnname + 'fixname' from tablename
```

To Update

```
update tablename set column = 'fixname' + column
```